# How to implement Dijkstra's Algorithm to find the shortest path in Java

Tags: java, dijkstra

I am absolutely confused on what to do. I'm trying to code off of the pseudo code that wikipedia has on Dijkstra's with priority queues, but I'm having a tough time making the adjustments to fit what i need to find. This is my (incomplete) code so far, and any help would be very much appreciated.

```
public int doDijkstras (String startVertexName, String endVertexName, ArrayList< String > shortestPath) {
        PriorityQueue<QEntry> q = new PriorityQueue<QEntry>();
        int cost = 0;
        int newCost;
        QEntry pred = null;
        for (String s : this.getVertices()) {
            if (!s.equals(startVertexName)) {
                cost = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                pred = null;
            }
            q.add(new QEntry(s, cost, pred, adjacencyMap.get(s)));
        }

        while (!q.isEmpty()) {
            QEntry curr = getMin(q);
            for (String s : curr.adj.keySet()) {
                newCost = curr.cost + this.getCost(curr.name, s);
                QEntry v = this.getVert(q, s);
                if (newCost < v.cost) {
                    v.cost = newCost;
                    v.pred = curr;
                    if (!q.contains(curr)) {
                        q.add(curr);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private QEntry getMin(PriorityQueue<QEntry> q) {
        QEntry min = q.peek();
        for (QEntry temp : q) {
            if (min.cost > temp.cost) {
                min = temp;
            }
        }
        return min;
    }

    private QEntry getVert(PriorityQueue<QEntry> q, String s) {
        for (QEntry temp : q) {
            if (temp.name.equals(s)) {
                return temp;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    class QEntry {
        String name;
        int cost;
        QEntry pred;
        TreeMap<String, Integer> adj;

        public QEntry(String name, int cost, QEntry pred, TreeMap<String, Integer> adj) {
            this.name = name;
            this.cost = cost;
            this.adj = adj;
            this.pred = pred;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, first post was trying to figure out how.

Comment: `QEntry curr = getMin(q);`--Why do you do such things with `q`? If you override `QEntry#compareTo()` method or create `q` with custom comparator, you could get min entry just by `q.poll()`

Comment: What in particular are you having trouble with?  Is there something you don't know how to translate into Java?  (What?)  Else, what's the problem?

Comment: I have no clue how to proceed from this point onward. What do i do to add the shortestpath to the ArrayList given and to return the cost of the shortestpath

Answer (score 1):

You are overlooking an important part of the algorithm: when to stop.

The pseudocode on Wikipedia is for the variation on Dijkstra's algorithm that computes the shortest path from the start node to *every* node connected to it.  Commentary immediately following the big pseudocode block explains how to modify the algorithm to find only the path to a specific target, and after that is a shorter block explaining how to extract paths.

In English, though, as you're processing your priority queue, you need to watch for the target element being the one selected.  When (if ever) it is, you know that no shorter path to it can be discovered than the one having the cost recorded in the target's queue entry, and represented (in reverse order) by that entry and its chain of predecessors.  You fill the path list by walking the chain of predecessors, and you return the value that was recorded in the target queue entry.

Note, however, that in your code, in the event that the start and target vertexes are not connected in the graph (including if the target is not in the graph at all), you will eventually drain the queue and fall out the bottom of the while loop without ever reaching the target.  You have to decide what to do with the path list and what to return in that case.

Note, too, that your code appears to have several errors, among them:

- In the event that the start vertex name is not the first one in the iteration order of `this.getVertices()`, its queue entry will not be initialized with cost 0, and will not likely be the first element chosen from the queue.
- If the specified start vertex is not in the graph at all then your code will run, and may emit a path, but its output in that case is bogus.
- Your queue elements (type `QEntry`) do not have a natural order; to create a `PriorityQueue` whose elements have such a type, you must provide a `Comparator` that defines their relative priorities.
- You are using your priority queue as a plain list.  That in itself will not make your code produce wrong results, but it *does* increase its asymptotic complexity.
- Be aware, however, that if you use the standard `PriorityQueue` *as* a priority queue, then you must never modify an enqueued object in a way that could change its order relative to any other enqueued object; instead, remove it from the queue first, modify it, then enqueue it again.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help (especially in pointing out my errors). I apologize for my awful code. My teacher is not  very good at teaching beginners (often makes references to materials not gone over in class therefore causing confusing), and I am fairly new to coding.